# Load a page into a div with Ajax

Tags: php, theme-development, ajax, html

I'm really a noob when it comes to Wordpress, right now I'm working on a theme that basically is all static, if you want to edit something you'll have to edit the .php file than rather doing it on the admin. It is a landing page where you click a menu button and a modal appears with the content, to do this I followed [this tutorial](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/02/how-to-supercharge-your-sites-speed-with-ajax-and-jquery/) which is not exactly Wordpress-oriented. I'm loading static pages via ajax and I really want to change this to editable Wordpress pages but I have no idea how to do it. I don't post the code because everything is like in the tutorial, I haven't used functions.php or anything. **How would you call the content of a page to load as if it was a static page just like in that tutorial?**

**EDIT**
The ajax call

```
$(function() {
    $('.w-container .w-nav-menu a').click(function() {
        var $linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
        var $pageRoot = $linkClicked.replace('#', '');
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $(".w-container .w-nav-menu a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/load.php",
                data: 'page='+$pageRoot,
                dataType: "html",
                beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#canvasloader-container.wrapper').show();
                    },
                complete: function(){
                        $('#canvasloader-container.wrapper').hide();
                    },                
                success: function(msg){
                    if((msg))
                    {
                        $('.content').html(msg);
                        $('.content').hide().fadeIn();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    event.preventDefault();
});

var hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.replace(/^#/, '');
switch (hash) {
    case 'products' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;      
    case 'about' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
    case 'storelocator' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
    case 'media' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
    case 'faq' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
    case 'contact' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
    }
});
```

**load.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST['page']);
$page = $_POST['page'];
if(file_exists('pages/'.$page.'.php'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/'.$page.'.php');
else echo 'Unavailable';
?>
```

I have only found tutorials with posts and that stuff, and that's not what I want.

Comment: You can treat Pages the same as Posts for most tutorials, if you ignore the archive lists. I've just had to do this for a page and I'll have a crack at an answer later today if no-one steps in before me.

Comment: Sounds cool! As I said, I'm a noob when it comes to Wordpress so any help is appreciated

Comment: In the mean time how have you structured your theme so far?

Comment: Everything is a mess right know, the footer and the header look pretty good. The index php is where my content is, that's why I want to make this cleaner and a little bit more customisable

Comment: Hmm. You need to let WP load your theme in its usual way rather than calling theme files directly. Might take me a while to whip up an answer. I've two sites to get live before Tuesday - can you wait till then?

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'll try to clean up the mess meanwhile with the help of the codex page.

Comment: Any news? @AndyMacaulay-Brook

Comment: Hi. Still snowed under but I've got your question bookmarked. I'd start by going with the way WP does things. Get your theme and site working with normal URLs rather than posting a page name. Then you can use Ajax to pull in a standard section of those pages.

Comment: Hi there. I've had a look at the article you mention and can see you're taking the second approach with Ajax and PHP. What I'm going to do is rework the article code to do things the WordPress way. If a user requests one of the pages you are loading directly, should they get a Page not found error, or load the page anyway, or something else?

Comment: Maybe they can be redirected to the front page? , @AndyMacaulay-Brook

Comment: What theme files do you have? Are you generating a normal Wordpress nav menu?

Comment: Due to I'm using special attributes I'm creating the menu myself instead of creating one with Wordpress. The theme files that I have are header, footer, index, 404 (not being used by now). The content would be a front page (I haven't changed that)

Comment: Anything? @AndyMacaulay-Brook

Comment: Hello, mate @AndyMacaulay-Brook, are you still able to help me?

Comment: I reckon it'd take me two days solid work to work it out thoroughly. Sorry I've been quiet, just a lot on. I'll put my general approach to it in an answer though.

Answer (score 1):

My philosophy is that if you use a system like WP then you embrace it and do things the WP way. WP has plenty of hooks that let you override functionality and the flexible theme structure gives you almost total control over the output.

So, I'd advise using a WP theme and WP built in menus. Your menu items will link to normal WP pages. The site will work for those without JS.

Use jQuery to put click events onto the menu links which use jQuery AJAX calls to the requested pages. These calls can strip the HTML returned back to a particular element (`main` is a good one if the theme uses it).

I haven't thought through how you'd handle your hashes yet.